# bibtex entry bringing captial words in line dashes and white space remove from references

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have a bibtex entry as follows

```
@misc{WhatisCl88:online,
    author = {Microsoft},
    title = {What is Cloud App Security? | Microsoft Docs},
    howpublished = {\url{https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-app-security/what-is-cloud-app-security}},
    month = {},
    year = {},

}
```

the bibliography that is generated

```
\documentclass[oneside,mtp]{iiitg}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
  \clearemptydoublepage
  \bibliography{biblio.bib}
```

the full document class can be seen [here](https://github.com/kiotie32/original-template)
[image: generated bibliography]
in the generated bibliography the Microsoft Docs is in small words.
I had written in bib file it in captial words.So how can I generate it as 
I wrote in bibliography.Also the spacing between has horizontal dash ---- how can I remove such dashes and such white spaces which do not have dashes but have blank space and then next letter in references start far off.

Comment: Probably `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` helps.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but still something that should be fixed: The correct syntax for `\bibliography` does **not** include the file extension (`.bib`). **It should be `\bibliography{biblio}`** and not `\bibliography{biblio.bib}`. TeX live systems usually accept the incorrect inclusion of `.bib`, but MikTeX systems (at least on Windows) will not.