# Variable name ended by end of line.. ...t in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

In the following [thesis.tex](https://github.com/kiotie32/thesissokoeradoera/blob/master/thesis.tex) file bibliography

```
   \documentclass[oneside,mtp]{iiitg}
\let\mydegree\degree
\let\degree\relax
% The BYUPhys class provides the following macros:
%
%   \makepreliminarypages : Makes the preliminary pages
%   \clearemptydoublepage : same as \cleardoublepage but doesn't put page numbers
%                           on blank intervening pages
%   \singlespace          : switch to single spaced lines
%   \doublespace          : switch to double spaced lines
%
% --------------------------- Load Packages ---------------------------------

% The graphicx package allows the inclusion of figures.  Plain LaTeX and
% pdfLaTeX handle graphics differently. The following code checks which one
% you are compiling with, and switches the graphicx package options accordingly.



\usepackage{makecell,tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
%\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\usepackage{longtable}
%usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
%usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{changepage,ifthen}
%\textwidth 6.5in
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}
%\textheight 10in
%\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1in}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{2}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\newcommand{\kthead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{arydshln}
%\algtext*{EndIf}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}

%\usepackage[lined,algonl,algochapter,algoruled]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

%\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\newcommand {\g}[1]{\textcolor[gray]{0.6} {#1}}
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\textcolor{red}{TODO: #1}\\}
\newcommand{\done}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{Tried to address. #1}\\}

% these are for the algorithms style file, for writing algorithms
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
%\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\begin{small}/* #1 */\end{small}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{/* #1 */}

% The fancyhdr package allows you to easily customize the page header.
% The settings below produce a nice, well separated header.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername \ \thechapter \ \ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ \ #1}}

% The caption package allows us to change the formatting of figure captions.
% The commands here change to the suggested caption format: single spaced and a bold tag
% Change the \DeclareCaptionFormat line below to make the captions fully bold
\usepackage{caption}
%\DeclareCaptionFormat{suggested}{\singlespace#1#2 #3\par\doublespace}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{suggested}{\singlespace \textbf{#1}\textbf{#2}#3 \doublespace}
\captionsetup{format=suggested}

%To instruct Latex to try to fit each paragraph into 1 less line
%\let\markeverypar\everypar
%\newtoks\everypar
%\everypar\markeverypar
%\markeverypar{\the\everypar\looseness=-1\relax}

%\newcommand{\captionfonts}{\small}

% The cite package cleans up the way citations are handled.  For example, it
% changes the citation [1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10,11] into [1-3,6-11].  If your advisor
% wants superscript citations, use the overcite package instead of the cite package.
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage[tone]{tipa}

% The makeidx package makes your index for you.  To make an index entry,
% go to the place in the book that should be referenced and type
%  \index{key}
% An index entry labeled "key" (or whatever you type) will then
% be included and point to the correct page.
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex


%koeradoera commented above 2 lines
% If you have a lot of equations, you might be interested in the amstex package.
% It defines a number of environments and macros that are helpful for mathematics.
% We don't do much math in this example, so we haven't used amstex here.w%
% To include a link in your pdf use \href{URL}{Text to be displayed}.  If your
% display text is the URL, you probably should use the \url{} command discussed
% above.
%
% To add a bookmark in the pdf you can use \pdfbookmark.  You can look up its usage
% in the hyperref package documentation
%\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,pdfpagelabels=true,plainpages=false,colorlinks=true,
%linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\urlstyle{rm}
%\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
%koeradoera commented above 4 lines
%koeradoera changed urlcolor=blue to black
%koeradoera added above 3 lines
\usepackage{program}
%above line koeradoera added

\usepackage{comment}
%above line added by koeradoera
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% ---------------- Fill in these fields for the preliminary pages -------------------
%
% For Senior and honors this is the year and month that you submit the thesis
% For Masters and PhD, this is your graduation date

\newcommand{\bigsize}{\fontsize{14pt}{20pt}\selectfont}

\Year{1988}
\Month{Alp}
\Author{koeradoera CCC}
\mydegree{Master }
% If you have a long title, split it between two lines. The \TitleBottom field defines the second line
% A two line title should be an "inverted pyramid" with the top line longer than the bottom.
\TitleTop{{\bigsize \bf BBB}}
%\TitleBottom{{\bigsize \bf  MEMORY SYSTEMS }}
%\TitleBottomagain{{\bigsize \bf MEMORY SYSTEMS}}
% Your research advisors
\AdvisorA{{Dr. AAAAA BBB}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% APPROVAL BY DSC %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%\Approval{
%\singlespace
%\hspace{6cm}
%%Date:\hspace{.8cm}$\backslash \ \ \ \ \  \ \backslash$ 20  \\  \\
%Date:\hspace{.8cm}$/ \ \ \ \ \  \ /$ 20  \\  \\
%Certified that the thesis entitled {\bf ``TITLE OF THE THESIS''} submitted by NAME OF THE AUTHOR to the somehwere, for the award of the degree of Master of Arts has been accepted by examiners and that the student has successfully defended the thesis in the viva-voce examination held today.
%
%\vspace{0.5in}
%
%%\noindent
%%Signature:~~~~~~~~~~\hfill Signature:~~~~~\hfill Signature:\hfill~
%
%%\noindent
%%Name:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\hfill Name:~~~~~~~~~~\hfill Name:~~~~~\hfill~
%
%\vspace{1in}
%\noindent
%(Member)~~~~~\hfill(Member)~~~~~\hfill(Member)
%
%\vspace{0.3in}
%%\hspace{2cm}
%%Signature:
%\vspace{1in}
%%\hspace{2cm}
%%Name:
%\noindent
%%\hspace{2cm}
%(Supervisor) %~~~~~\hfill(Supervisor 2)
%
%
%
%\vspace{0.3in}
%
%%\hspace{2cm}
%%Name:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\hfill Name:~~~~~\hfill ~~~~
%
%%\vspace{1in}
%%%\hspace{2cm}
%%\noindent
%%(External Examiner)\hspace{0.8in}(Chairman)
%}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CERTIFICATE BY SUPERVISOR %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\Certificate{
    %\noindent%
    {\em This is to certify that the thesis entitled {\bf ``BBB''}, submitted by {\bf koeradoera CCC} to the somehwere, for the award of the degree of Master of Technology, is a record of bona fide research work carried out by him under my supervision and guidance.
    %  Diploma.}

    \signaturebox{Dr. AAAAA BBB,\\ Assistant Professor,\\Department of Computer Science and Engineering\\somehwere}
    %\hspace{10pt}
    %\signaturebox{Name of the Supervisor 2,\\ Designation,\\Department of Computer Science and Engineering\\somehwere}

    \datebox 
    %\vskip 0pt plus 2fill
    %\noindent Accepted for the Department\hfill%
    %\signaturebox{\@DepRep, \@DepRepTitle\\Department of Physics and
    %Astronomy }{} \vfill \noindent Accepted for the College\hfill
    %\signaturebox{\@Dean, \@DeanTitle \\
    %College of Mathematics and Physical Sciences}

}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DECLARATION BY STUDENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\Declaration{
    \noindent
    I certify that
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[a.]   Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing  
        \item[b.]   Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing  
        \item[c.]   Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing  
        \item[d.]   Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing  
        \item[e.]   Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing  
        \item[f.]   Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing Some random thing  
    \end{enumerate}

    \vspace{0.6in}

    \hfill koeradoera CCC ~ ~ ~
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ACKNOWLEDGMENTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\Acknowledgments{
    \input{texfiles/acknowledgments}
    \medskip
    \bigskip\medskip
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ABSTRACT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%The text of your abstract
\Abstract{
    \input{texfiles/abstract}
}

\fussy

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}


\normalsize
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
%\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]
%\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
%\graphicspath{ {/home/arya/Desktop/synopsis_seminar/figures/} }
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }


\begin{document}
    % Start page counting in roman numerals
    \frontmatter

    % This command makes the formal preliminary pages.
    % You can comment it out during the drafting process if you want to save paper.

    \makepreliminarypages

    \singlespace

    \clearemptydoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \hspace{-0.3cm}{\huge \textbf{List of Abbreviations}}\\
    %  \end{center}
    \input{texfiles/abrreviation}

    \clearemptydoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    %\hspace{-0.4cm}{\huge \textbf{List of Symbols}}\\
    %  \end{center}
    %\input{texfiles/symbol}
    %above three lines commented by koeradoera removing symbol table
    \clearemptydoublepage
    %\makepreliminarypages
    % Make the table of contents.
    \tableofcontents

    \clearemptydoublepage

    % Make the list of figures
    \listoffigures
    \clearemptydoublepage

    % Make the list of tables
    \listoftables
    \clearemptydoublepage

    %\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols and Abbreviation}
    %\include{files/symb_b}
    %\include{files/symb_b1}
    %\clearemptydoublepage

    \onehalfspace

    % Start regular page counting at page 1
    \mainmatter
    \addtolength{\parskip}{0.05\baselineskip}

    \abovedisplayskip=13pt
    \belowdisplayskip=13pt

    \clearemptydoublepage
    \input{texfiles/chapter1}
    \clearemptydoublepage
    \input{texfiles/chapter2}
    \clearemptydoublepage
    \input{texfiles/chapter3}
    \clearemptydoublepage
    \input{texfiles/chapter4}
    \clearemptydoublepage
    \input{texfiles/conclusion}
    \clearemptydoublepage

    %\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
    %\clearemptydoublepage
    %\singlespace
    %\bibliography{biblio}


    %\cite{*}
    %\bibliographystyle{plain}
    %\bibliographystyle{alpha}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \clearemptydoublepage
    \bibliography{biblio}
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}

    %\input{texfiles/flat}
    %\clearemptydoublepage
    %\input{texfiles/nest}
    %\clearemptydoublepage
    %\input{texfiles/intent}
    %\clearemptydoublepage
    %\input{texfiles/lm}
    %\clearemptydoublepage
    %\input{texfiles/conclusions}
    %\clearemptydoublepage

    %\appendix

    %\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
    %\clearemptydoublepage
    %\singlespace
    %\bibliography{thesis}

    % \include{AppendixA}
    % \clearemptydoublepage
    % \include{AppendixB}
    % \clearemptydoublepage

    %\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
    %\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1} \small \normalsize
    \clearemptydoublepage

    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Author's Biography} %Optional
    \input{texfiles/cv}
\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\if 0

\begin{figure}[tb]
    \centerline{
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./figures/}
    }
    \caption{{\bf }}
    \label{fig:}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure*}[tb]
    \centerline{
        \subfloat[{\bf }]{\includegraphics[height=0.3\textwidth,width=3.5cm,angle=-90]{./figures/}}
        \hfil
        \subfloat[{\bf }]{\includegraphics[height=0.3\textwidth,width=3.5cm,angle=-90]{./figures/}}
        \hfil
        \subfloat[{\bf }]{\includegraphics[height=0.3\textwidth,width=3.5cm,angle=-90]{./figures/}}
    }
    \caption{{\bf }}
    \label{fig:}
\end{figure*}

\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

thesis.bbl file generates automatically

```
\bibitem{WhatisCl88:online}
Microsoft.
\newblock What is cloud app security? | microsoft docs.
\newblock
  \url{https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-app-security/what-is-cloud-app-security}.
```

in the [biblio.bib](https://github.com/kiotie32/thesissokoeradoera/blob/master/biblio.bib) file it is defined as

```
@misc{WhatisCl88:online,
    author = {Microsoft},
    title = {What is Cloud App Security? | Microsoft Docs},
    howpublished = {\url{https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-app-security/what-is-cloud-app-security}},
    month = {},
    year = {},

}
```

it is generating error

```
Variable name ended by end of line.. ...t is cloud app security? | microsoft docs.
```

I am using Miktex 2.9 on Windows 10
Full thesis [here](https://github.com/kiotie32/thesissokoeradoera)

Comment: What exactly is the difference to your previous question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/544303/134144

Comment: Please provide a complete [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` has no effect previously when I posted the question things were working perfectly fine. but this time program is not compiling and generating errors. I updated all changes on github. The previous time I typed question there was some output this time there is no output only errors.